# BaseAdapter selecting item issue

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which extends BaseAdapter. I have a  array list. The ListView inflates and populates correctly. I am using the flipper view to change the layout to another but the problem is when i clicked on the first item it rotate but the item at third or sixth row will also rotate
list view how can i fix it i only want the image is change of selected item

```
    ArrayList<product_data> al=new ArrayList<product_data>();
class product_data
{
    String post_title;
    String newprice;
    String oldprice;
    String image;
    String id;
    product_data(String post_title,String newprice,String oldprice,String image,String id)
    {
        this.post_title=post_title;
        this.newprice=newprice;
        this.oldprice=oldprice;
        this.image=image;
        this.id=id;

    }
}
```

to add data in arraylist

```
try {
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                JSONObject userDetails = parentObject.getJSONObject("response"); 
                JSONArray jarray=userDetails.getJSONArray("products_data");
                   for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
                   {
                       System.out.println("From the Dataaaa");
                       JSONObject c = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                       String details=c.getString("details");
                       String image=c.getString("image");
                       String catagory=c.getString("catagory");
                       String new_price=c.getString("new_price");
                       String title=c.getString("title");
                       String id1=c.getString("id");
                       System.out.println("from ther first image"+image);
                       System.out.println("from the sdafdfadf"+details);

                       al.add(new product_data(title, new_price, new_price, image, id1));
```

Adapter class

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View singleView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int ok=position;

        if(singleView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            singleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_ist_layout,parent,false);
            System.out.println("from the if"+position);
            viewAnimator = (ViewAnimator)singleView.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
             rootLayout = (View)singleView.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_root);
             cardFace = (View)singleView.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_card_face);
             cardBack = (View) singleView.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_card_back);
        }

            System.out.println("from the else");


        System.out.println("Position in else"+position);
        product_data a=al.get(position);
        TextView tv1=(TextView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv2=(TextView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tv3=(TextView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            /**
             * Bind a click listener to initiate the flip transitions
             */
            viewAnimator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { 
                    // This is all you need to do to 3D flip

                    AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);
                }

            });



            cardFace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("positon"+ok);
                    AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);

                }
            });


         cardBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);
                }
            });

        imgview1=(ImageView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
         imgview1.setTag(position);
        imgview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int position1=(Integer)v.getTag();
                  System.out.println(position1);
                  String id=al.get(position1).id;
                  System.out.println("id from the list"+id);
                Intent in=new Intent(product_list_Activity.this,rating_dialog.class);
                in.putExtra("id",id);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    ImageView   imgview2=(ImageView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
         imgview2.setTag(position);
        imgview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int position1=(Integer)v.getTag();
                  System.out.println(position1);
                  String id=al.get(position1).id;
                  System.out.println("id from the list"+id);
                Intent in=new Intent(product_list_Activity.this,product_review.class);
                in.putExtra("id",id);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        tv3.setTag(position);
        tv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int position1=(Integer)v.getTag();
                System.out.println("from the review "+position1);
                String id=al.get(position1).id;
                globalvariables.product_id=id;
                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),review_product_tabbar.class);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
        tv1.setText(a.post_title);
        tv2.setText("$"+a.oldprice);
        tv1.setTypeface(tf);
        tv2.setTypeface(tf);
        tv3.setTypeface(tf);
        int loader = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        ImageView image = (ImageView)singleView. findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imgLoader.DisplayImage(a.image, loader, image);
        Animation anim = new Rotate3dAnimation(90.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, false, singleView);
        anim.setDuration(1000l);
        singleView.startAnimation(anim);


        return singleView;
    }
}
```

}
[image]

when i click on the first item it rotate and another view is coming

but when i scrolled the fourth item in below image will also rotate

[image]

i am using the on click listner on the relative views as in the code

Comment: Maybe you can add some code snippets?

Comment: Can you post the code of the adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

I have one idea on click of image first try to get Position and when you get Position then set new image background at that position.